# FileSystemObject.GetFile not capable of handling files with a single quote or apostrophe in the filename?

Tags: vba, excel

FileSystemObject.GetFile() gets a "file not found" error if you call it on a filename with a single quote/apostrophe in it, ie:

```
FileSystemObject.GetFile("D:\somepath\some file with an ' apostrophe in it.txt")
```

Here's what I'm attempting:

```
Public Sub VBA_GetFileInfo(FileName As String, ByRef outDateCreated As Date, ByRef outDateAccessed As Date, ByRef outDateModified As Date, ByRef outFileSize As Long)

Dim tmpFile As String
'SOME THINGS I'VE TRIED TO OVERCOME THE PROBLEM, WITH NO SUCCESS:
'tmpFile = """" & FileName & """"
'tmpFile = FileName
'tmpFile = Replace(tmpFile, "\", "\\")
'tmpFile = Replace(tmpFile, "'", "\'")


Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim f As file
Dim s As String
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
----> BLOWS UP HERE with "file not found" error:
Set f = fso.GetFile(tmpFile)
```

Comment: Where did Powershell come in here?

Comment: As this should be fine are you sure it is an apostrophe - it may be a ` rather than `'` ?

Comment: "may be a ` rather than '" - hmmm...in which case my attempted fixes may not have worked.  Would ` cause issues just like "'" would?

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue at all - I think your problem may be an incorrect file name. So suggest you a) right click your file name in explorer b) rename c) copy the exact file name with ctrl c d) paste that into your `tmpFile` variable as is and retry your code

Comment: Even I have tested the above code and it works fine. My guess is the same as brettdj. It could be an incorrect filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

brettdj's comment:

> As this should be fine are you sure it is an apostrophe - it may be a
>   ` rather than '

...turns out to have been the correct answer, it must have been apostrophe's rather than single quotes causing the error.